# MYSQL - All the tables and varchar columns of our database were changed to latin and swedish collation

Tags: mysql, grails, character-encoding, grails-orm

We are using GRAILS 2.5 and GORM in a project and Mysql 5.7. We detected suddenly we have in our database latin charset and swedish collation and should be utf8. What can be the reason of having everything changed?

maybe a bad my.cnf config from our IT provider? Our own fault? we didn'd do anything special in our grails application that can provoke a charset change

Comment: The datatbase/table/column collation cannot be changed hiddenly or implicitly - explicit ALTER query needed. Are you sure that you speak about data storing collation? maybe you look at server or connection collation?

Comment: Nono, we found by checking our DB tables and columns that everything was setted to encoding: cp1252 West, collation: latin1_swdish_ci. Just a normal deployment of our grails application.

Comment: *we found by checking our DB tables and columns* I.e. this is the info from SHOW CREATE TABLE? If so then explicit altering queries were executed.

Comment: Also `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'char%';`